# How to get the HID country code information when connecting the Smart KBD to the iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, external-accessory

I want to develop an APP to get the HID country code information (keyboard language layout) when connecting the Smart KBD to the iPad.

Is it possible? And how to get the HID country code information?

Thanks for your help.